# Javascript tr click event with newly created rows (Updating css)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I am very new to web development. I am currently using [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) jquery plugin to create a dynamic table, where the user can add and delete rows. I am having trouble with changing the background color of **newly** created rows upon clicking. It works fine with rows that are hard coded in html. Here is the relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('table.tablesorter td').click(
            function (event) {
                $(this).parent('tr').toggleClass('rowclick');
                $(this).parent('tr').siblings().removeClass('rowclick');
        });
    }
)
```

rowclick is a CSS class here:

```
table.tablesorter tbody tr.rowclick td {
    background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
```

I have tried adding the following to my Javascript function that adds a new row:

```
var createClickHandler = 
        function(newrow) {
            return function(event) {
                //alert(newrow.cells[0].childNodes[0].data);
                newrow.toggleClass('rowclick');
                newrow.siblings().removeClass('rowclick');
            };
        }
row.onclick = createClickHandler(row);
```

The alert correctly displays the text in the first column of the row when I click the new row. However, my new rows do not respond to the CSS class. Anyone have any ideas?

I should also mention that I have updated the tablesorter before applying the clickHandler with:

```
$("#TASKTABLE").trigger("update");
$("#TASKTABLE").trigger("appendCache");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegate your clickable `td` elements like:

```
$('table.tablesorter').on('click','td', function(){
```

using `.on()` from jQuery 1.7:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event >handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(), .delegate(), >and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see .off(). To attach an event that runs >only once and then removes itself, see .one()

Comment: Thanks, works great now. What does this actually do? Why didn't my previous version work?

Comment: This is a newer jQuery method to replace the now deprecated `.live()` method. What is actually does is waiting for existent and **future** created `td` elements, by delegating to them the click event. Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/on

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(newrow).toggleClass('rowclick');
$(newrow).siblings().removeClass('rowclick');
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!!! Been stuck on this all day. What does $() actually mean. I kinda jumped right into this project with 0 html/javascript experience.

Comment: @yalechen you are welcome, `$()` is jQuery selector which returns a jQuery object, then you can use jQuery methods for manipulating selected elements.